# why dilate functin give different result when the parameteer is the same

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I try to dilate three image of characters in java opencv. i found out than ever it same character with same font and size, after dilate the result is different. so i try with same image the result is still different. Here is my test code.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            Mat InputSrc = openFile("src\\myOpencv\\ocr\\crop1.png");
            Mat tempImg =new Mat();
            Imgproc.cvtColor(InputSrc, tempImg, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            Imgproc.threshold(tempImg, tempImg, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
            imageViewer.show(tempImg, "src");
            Mat kernal5 = new Mat(5, 5, CV_8U);
            Point midPoint = new Point(-1, -1);
            Scalar scalarOne = new Scalar(1);
            Mat binImg2 = new Mat();
            Imgproc.dilate(tempImg, binImg2, kernal5, midPoint, 1, 1, scalarOne);
            imageViewer.show(binImg2, "dilate");
        }
```

thank

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide your test input image, and also show us the three different results you get. Please, add those 4 images to your question.

Comment: you don't initialize the kernel with any value... so it'll contain random values. So just: `Mat kernal5 = new Mat(5, 5, CV_8U, 255);` (or whatever the Java syntax is...)